Как расставить запятые в куплете?
Как следует расставить запятые в куплете?
Смертельный яд — /
В нём жажда дорог, /
Растаявший дым(,) /
И(,) следом за ним(,) /
Развенчаный Бог.

Я бы записала так:
Яд —
Трепет надежды 
В миг нашей встречи,
Солнечный ветер
С нас сбросил одежды.
Смертельный яд —
В нём жажда дорог,
Растаявший дым,
И следом за ним —
Развенчанный Бог

Технология — ЯД | Текст песни,  https://pesni.guru
Пояснение
В тексте используется стилистическая фигура — именительный темы (яд, смертельный яд), после него ставится тире. Синтаксис такой:
(1) В нём жажда дорог, Растаявший дым — эллиптическое предложение.
(2) И следом за ним — Развенчанный Бог — эллиптическое предложение.
Эллипсис строится по схеме: обстоятельство/дополнение  — подлежащее
Между предложениями бессоюзная связь (запятая).

А пять плюсов можно поставить?!.

Александр? Как приятно вас видеть!!  Я по тексту комментария думала, что меня автор вопроса так оценил.  Да за что же пять?   Я как раз пишу и думаю:  Мне это совсем не трудно, почему бы не ответить. Ведь людям надо...  Правильные такие мысли)  Спасибо!  А может, тогда уж переведете четверостишье из Шекспира, а?

Ой, вы там такие все умные... Поверите, нет? Думаю, дай-ка наугад выберу номер сонета... и поражаюсь, читая этот же, 130-й. Потом выбрал другой, прочитал в трёх переводах, вот сижу обалдеваю!..

Нужно выбирать сонеты влюбленного Шекспира, начиная со 127-го. Так что вы правильно попали.  И тогда ум  не особенно нужно, только чувства и художественный талант)

Вернее было не наугад, а осознанно, это число мне говорит о многом, личном...
